# How to installing sha1sum in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, sha1

Problem:
To get the sha1sum value of a file in MAC OS i run the following command

```
sha1sum file_name
```

The error I got is following

```
perl version 5.18.2 can't run /usr/bin/sha1sum.  Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/sha1sum5.16 (uses perl 5.16)

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```

I tried to install **textutils and coreutils**, but both failed. Can anyone suggest me how I can resolve the issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you just alias `sha1sum` to `/usr/bin/sha1sum5.16`?

Comment: I am calling sha1sum from python script, not just trying to find one specific file.

Comment: I understand that but is that really even relevent? I assume you are just executing the shell script/binary so what Im saying just use a symlink or alias to execute the binary you need. Obviously the command you want exists, its just name differently for the installed version of Perl and OS. Also, I find it hard to believe Python doesn't have a tool for getting a sha1 checksum - why arent you using that so you have fewer external dependencies?

Comment: Also as far as installing did you try using Macports or Homebrew?

Comment: I'd rather do the hashing directly in Python code instead of calling out to external programs. It's a little more code, but probably more efficient. It also rids you of external dependencies. See http://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-files-with-python/.

Comment: @prodigitalson, yes I tried both Macports or Homebrew. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 60):

You can install it in Mac OS using homebrew with `brew install md5sha1sum`. Got the info from this link https://raamdev.com/2008/howto-install-md5sum-sha1sum-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I see no difference in functionality for my use case from the native `shasum` command. My output for `echo -n "test" | shasum` is identical to the output for `echo -n "test" | sha1sum`, for example.

Comment: Yes but if you want your old linux scripts to just work in MacOS *and* keep working on Linux, this solution is the best.

Answer (score 44):

MacOS has `shasum` preinstalled, which calculates `sha1` sum by default:

```
$ shasum --help
Usage: shasum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print or check SHA checksums.
With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -a, --algorithm   1 (default), 224, 256, 384, 512, 512224, 512256
[...]
```

Usage example:

```
$ echo -n "test" | shasum
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3  -
```

Also `openssl sha1` does the job:

```
$ echo -n "test" | openssl sha1
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

Comment: Both of them are hash of empty string because you have error in your command. correct way to use it is to echo the string
```
echo -n "test" | openssl sha1 or
echo -n "test" | shasum
```

Comment: @itmard you're right! I've updated the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use shasum or openssl to calculate the hash

```
echo -n "yourpassword" | openssl sha1
b48cf0140bea12734db05ebcdb012f1d265bed84


echo -n "yourpassword" | shasum
b48cf0140bea12734db05ebcdb012f1d265bed84
```